# Why do I get twice in a row empty values as result?

Tags: json, cell, decode, swift4.2

I would like to load image from api into UIImageView inside cell. But since i receive nill values two times in row first, i m not able to do it. 
Here is my code:

```
class MainController: UITableViewController{

    var nulti = [Nulti]()
    var picture = Picture()
    let urlDel = "http://xx"
    let urlPic = "http://xxx/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 44
        getNulti()
    }

    func getNulti(){
        Alamofire.request(urlDel, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    guard let responseData = response.data else {return}
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    self.nulti = try! jsonDecoder.decode([Nulti].self, from: responseData)
                    for pic in self.nulti{
                        let id = pic.image 
                        if(id != nil){
                            self.getPicture(id: id!.description)
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }
           }
    }

    func getPicture(id: String){
        Alamofire.request(urlPic + id, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    guard let responseData = response.data else {return}
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    self.picture = try! jsonDecoder.decode(Picture.self, from: responseData)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }
           }
    }

    func picConvertor(id : String) -> UIImage{
        let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: id, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
        return decodedimage!
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nulti.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell//
        cell.cell?.text = nulti[indexPath.row].name
        print(self.picture)
        //let id = self.picture.image!.description
        //cell.logo?.image = picConvertor(id: id)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Then i did print(self.picture) to see what's going on, and then i saw this

Picture(id: nil, format: nil, image: nil)

Picture(id: nil, format: nil, image: nil)

Picture(id: Optional(2), format: Optional("png"), image: Optional("iVBORw0KGgoAAA...")

Picture(id: Optional(2), format: Optional("png"), image: Optional("iVBORw0KGg...")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the temporal order of your code is not the written order. Your `getPicture` is asynchronous. A given picture will arrive at some future unknown time. But your code just rushes right on regardless. Thus, in these lines:

```
                for pic in self.nulti{
                    let id = pic.image 
                    if(id != nil){
                        self.getPicture(id: id!.description)
                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
```

...you are reloading the table view *before* any pictures arrive:

```
                for pic in self.nulti{
                    let id = pic.image 
                    if(id != nil){
                        self.getPicture(id: id!.description)
                        // 2 a picture arrives...
                        // 3 another picture arrives...
                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData() // 1
```

And thus what you are doing can never work, funneling all photos thru one property.  When the pictures will arrive, and in what order, is completely unknown; thus you cannot "pick up" a picture from a property. Your code is asynchronous: you must deal with each photo as it arrives, asynchronously.

Comment: I have tired to use ur tutorial, but still i have problems with duplicated values

Comment: It's not a "tutorial" you can "use", it's an explanation. Your question was "Why do I get twice in a row empty values as result?" My answer explains that. The article and the two follow-up articles explain that. The problem of how to download images asynchronously into a table view has been explained here many, many times, so all you have to do is search.